# Cannot install extension in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1607

I am running the new Anniversary Update of Windows 10 and use the version of Microsoft Edge that comes with it.

Edge has a setting "Extensions" that leads you to the Windows Store to install extensions. After selecting Adblock and downloading it, Edge does not notify me that an extension was installed (like it did on the Anniversary Update preview on another machine).

Looking at the app/extension in the store again, it says that there was a problem with this app and re-installing it is recommended. It does not say anything about what kind of error happened. Re-installing does not help.

In the "Extensions" section of Edge no extension is listed.

Comment: I guess you'll have to wait until others gets the Anni.Update build :) They released it only few hrs before and hasn't appeared yet in WU. ISOs are available, though.

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: The anniversary update is a huge disappointment so far. What I was most looking for were extensions for Edge, because I like the browser...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a manual work-around:

- Go to Settings -> System -> Apps & Features
- Search for the AdBlock extension (or any other extension that is not correctly installed)
- Uninstall the app/extension
- Download the extension from the Store again

This made Edge detect the AdBlock extension. It's working fine now.

Comment: Had the same issue with LastPass, can confirm that this fixes it! Thanks!! :)

Comment: I read that removing all extensions was the key, but this is the first place I found that explains *how* to remove those extensions in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Removing just adblock didn't help. I had to remove ALL extensions. Only after this when I installed adblock again it appeared in the extension list of ms edge.